# Herkunft des Begriffs ~plan in Straßennamen

Tags: etymology

In Berlin existiert ein Viertel in Nähe des Flughafens Tempelhof, mit Straßennamen die auf 'Plan' enden:

- Bäumerplan
- Rumeyplan

[Link zu OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.de/karte.html?zoom=17&lat=52.47613&lon=13.37636&layers=B00F)

"Plan" kenne ich in zwei Bedeutungen: Glatt und Flach - aber in Berlin ist fast jede Straße flach und glatt - von Schlaglöchern durch Frost abgesehen. Das wäre ein seltsamer Bennungsgrund.

Noch seltsamer wäre die zweite Bedeutung als 'vorbereitetes Vorhaben' wie in 'Marshallplan'. Rumey war ein Kriegsflieger, kein Planer, nach dem man einen Plan benannt hätte, nachdem man wiederum eine Straße benennen würde.

Hat jemand eine plausible Erklärung für diesen Namensteil?

Comment: In Stockholm gibt es viele Plätze, die *-plan* heißen: Stureplan, Vasaplan, Karlaplan, Odenplan, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mit ***"Plan"*** wurde eine *"ebene Fläche, Platz"* bezeichnet:

> **Plan** m. ‘Fläche, Ebene, freier Platz’, mhd. *plān* m., *plān(e)* f. ‘freier Platz, Ebene, Turnier-, Kampfplatz’, entlehnt aus lat. *plānum* ‘Ebene, Fläche’, der substantivierten neutralen Form von lat. *plānus* (s. oben), bzw. (zumal in der Bedeutung ‘Kampfplatz’) aus afrz. *plain* m. (aus lat. *plānum*) und afrz. *plaine* f. (aus dem als fem. Singular aufgefaßten Plur. lat. *plāna*); letzteres lebt vereinzelt weiter in nhd. *Pläne* f. und (dem Frz. folgend) *Plaine* f. (bis 1. Hälfte 19. Jh.)<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=plan)</sup>

Heute ist diese Bedeutung verlorengegangen. Als einen *["Plan"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Plan_Vorhaben_Entwurf_Karte)* bezeichnet man neben der Bedeutung einer Absicht oder eines Entwurfs nur noch eine Karte, die natürlich auch eben ist.

In Straßennamen findet sich die ursprüngliche Wurzel aber noch im Niederländischen, in dem Straßen und Plätze vielfach noch mit *-plein* oder *-plaan* enden.

Answer (score 7):

*plan* = *glatt und flach* geht schon in die Richtung. [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Plan_Kampfplatz_Ebene) hilft weiter:

> mittelhochdeutsch plān(e) = ebener (Kampf)platz < mittellateinisch planum, zu lateinisch planus, plan

Daher stammt wohl auch die Redewendung *jemanden auf den Plan rufen*. Es gibt auch einen Kampfflieger [Paul Bäumer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_B%C3%A4umer), daher scheint das stimmig zu sein.

Comment: Bis auf den letzten Satz eine stimmige Antwort. Ein Kampfflieger kämpft ja eben nicht auf dem Feld oder einem Kampfplatz, und dass westlich des Flughafens ein Kampfplatz des 1. Weltkriegs gelegen haben könnte wäre mir auch neu.

Comment: @user unknown Damit nahm ich auch eher Bezug auf den in der Frage erwähnten anderen Flieger nach dem die andere Straße benannt ist. Da der zweite Name nicht erklärt wurde war ich nicht sicher ob die Herkunft bekannt war. Ob die Benennung an sich logisch ist oder nicht wollte ich damit nicht bewerten, sondern eher dass die Person die die Benennung vorgenommen hat das nach gewissen Regeln getan hat die für beide genannten Namen stimmig sind.

Comment: Aha. Diese 2x `Kampf` in enger Nähe haben mich dann fehlgeleitet.